# Bash script stops when running chromium

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, google-chrome, chromium

I have a bash script that runs a chromium instance, but the script won't continue executing until I close chromium.

Is there any way to run Chromium and continue the script? The same happens when executing `chromium` in the terminal, you can't continue using the terminal until you close the chromium instance.

[This solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392016/bash-script-stops-when-opening-chromium) is not working for me.

**Sample script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 == 'off' ]
then
echo "Chromium OFF"
pkill -x -15 chromium
else
echo "Chromium ON"
export DISPLAY=:0
chromium http://localhost/shopCaseCodeigniter/selectSlideshowForScreen/1 --kiosk --password-store=basic &
fi
```

Comment: Welcome! How did the solution not work? What have you tried specifically?

Comment: @guillermochamorro I tried this `chromium http://google.es --kiosk --password-store=basic &` This is inside a bash script

Comment: Maybe there's something in your script that triggers this behaviour. Would you share the relevant parts of it?

Comment: Can you submit a sample script?

Comment: @guillermochamorro post updated with a sample script

Comment: @cosmoscalibur post updated with a sample script